# Angular 2: How to preserve the state of the app across navigations to an external page?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a simple search engine in Angular 2. I have a component with a search field and a list of results leading to external URLs (to pages that are not part of the app) below the search field.

Let's say the user enters some search text, gets results from a service call in the background and then clicks on one of the results links which takes him to an external site. Then he perhaps decides to try some other result, so he clicks the Back button of his browser to get back to the search results. But the problem is that at this point the whole app gets reinitialized which means that the previous results are gone and the app just displays an empty search field as if it was opened for the very first time.

So, my question is: how do I preserve the state of the app across navigations to external sites? Do I have to use the Router and store the search string in the route? Or do I have to save the state somehow and restore it when the user returns back to the app? What is the recommended way of handling this use case?

Comment: *Do I have to use the Router and store the search string in the route?* Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 router 2.0.0 not reloading components when same url loaded with different parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533291/angular2-router-2-0-0-not-reloading-components-when-same-url-loaded-with-differe)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correct, you need your webpage's data to reappear as your left, when you  navigate from your angular app (say http://your-angular-app.com) to an external/alien  website (say http://alien-site.com) and navigate back to your angular app (http:..your-angular-app.com) by clicking the browser's 'back' button.

If thats the case, there are two possiblities that I can think of

1. Using **HTML5 localStorage**

Assume you have an input element like the following on your html page

```
<input [(ngModel)]="fieldModel1"></input>
```

And your component be,

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  public fieldModel1;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
   unloadNotification($event: any) {
    localStorage.setItem('fieldName1',this.fieldModel1)
    // and so on ...
  }

  constructor() {}

  // your code ....
}
```

and on page load you can fetch values from local storage and populate your screen

```
ngOnInit() {
   if(localStorage.getItem('fieldName1')) {
     this.fieldModel = localStorage.getItem('fieldName1');
   }
   // and so on ...
}
```

2. post form data to server on page unload and fetch it on page load - typically use server instead of localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You could store the state in localstorage. For instance if you make a search you can navigate to a url like this.

```
yourdomain.com/search?query=string
```

This will represent a route in Angular 2 this route will make the search.
Then use the query as key and store the state (result) for that key. If you navigate to that url again you can load the state from localstorage with that key.
Of course you need handle clearing old results but that's details.