# About Routing in Angular2

Tags: angular

Below code describes routes in my angular 2 application

```
 RouterModule.forRoot( [
              {path:'' , component:HomeComponent},
              {path:'acategories/:id/products/:pid' , component:ProductComponent},                 
              {path:'acategories/:id/products' , component:ProductsComponent},                  
              {path:'acart' , component:CartComponent},
              {path:'about' , component:AboutComponent},
              {path:'aorders' , component:OrderDetailsComponent},
              {path:'asearch' , component: ProductSearchComponent},
              {path:'**',component:PageNotFoundComponent}
          ])
```

My root component has links to these routes as depicted in below image

[image]

User searches for an item by entering text in textbox and clicking search button.Once the user clicks "search" , below method
in root component will be executed , which basically navigates to "asearch" route.

```
onSearch() 
{       

    if(this.formGroup.valid) 
    {
    this.router.navigate(['asearch' , {search:this.formGroup.controls['search'].value}]);
    }
}
```

Now the issue I am facing is , when "asearch" route is already active[ ie its the current active route"] and user tries
to search for an item , results are not displayed.

Below is the the code in ProductSearchComponent which gets the results from server.

```
  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('ngOnInit()');

    this.route.params.subscribe( (params) => {
        this.search = params['search'];
    })

    this.service.searchProducts(this.search).subscribe( {
                                                next: (data) => { 
                                                                    this.products = data;
                                                                },
                                                error: (err) => { this.toaster.error(err) }
                                             })

}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what code causes these results to be shown at all.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer , will update my question

Comment: Would it even work without a path like `{path:'asearch/:id' , component: ProductSearchComponent}` ?

Comment: Ensure you use `pathMatch: 'full'` for empty path routes that are not redirects and don't have child routes `{path:'' , component:HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},`

Comment: Now what I observed is , if  "asearch" is already active route , then ngOnInit() is not executing

Comment: I have fixed it , by placing the call to  "this.service.searchProducts" within the subscribe of "this.route.params"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When only route params change, the component is reused (instead of destroyed and recreated). You just need to move your code a bit to keep it working

```
  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('ngOnInit()');

    this.route.params.subscribe( (params) => {
      this.search = params['search'];

      this.service.searchProducts(this.search)
      .subscribe( {
        next: (data) => { 
          this.products = data;
        },
        error: (err) => { this.toaster.error(err) }
      })
    })
  }
```

Ensure you use `pathMatch: 'full'` for empty path routes that are not redirects and don't have child routes

```
{path:'' , component:HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
```

See also [Angular2 router 2.0.0 not reloading components when same url loaded with different parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533291/angular2-router-2-0-0-not-reloading-components-when-same-url-loaded-with-differe/39533351#39533351)

Comment: I did the same 1 min back , check my comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You are facing with the problem of subscribe/unsubscribe. You have to do next:

```
routeSubscriber: any;


ngOnInit() {

    this.routeSubscriber = this.route.params.subscribe( (params) => {
       this.search = params['search'];
    }) 
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSubscriber.unsubscribe();
}
```

The problem is that you are already subscribed, so you need to unsubscribe it before next try from same route.