# On query parameters change, route is not updating

Tags: angular, routes, query-string

In my application, there are multiple links in which I have some `links` with the same `route` but with different `query parameters`.

say, I have links like:

```
.../deposits-withdrawals
.../deposits-withdrawals?id=1
.../deposits-withdrawals?id=2&num=12321344
```

When I am in one of the above routes and native to the other route from above mentioned, the route is not changing. Not even any of the functions like `ngOnInit` or `ngOnChanges` being called.I have changed the parameters from `queryParameters` to `matrixParameters` but with no success. I have gone through many links and answers. But, none of them solved my problem. Help me how to solve this.

Thank you...

**EDIT:**

```
<button routerLink="/deposits-withdrawals" [queryParams]="{ type: 'deposit' ,'productId': selectedBalance.ProductId}" class="wallet-btns">DEPOSIT {{selectedBalance.ProductSymbol}}</button>
<button routerLink="/deposits-withdrawals" [queryParams]="{ type: 'withdrawal' ,'productId': selectedBalance.ProductId }" class="wallet-btns">WITHDRAW {{selectedBalance.ProductSymbol}}</button>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem once. Can you put some code, or solutions you tried?
I'll give you something working for me, but you better give me some more details so that I can help.
Supposing we are here :
**some_url*/deposits-withdrawals* and we wish to navigate , changing only parameters.

```js
    let url = "id=2&num=12321344"
    this.router.navigate(['../', url], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Hope it helps :/

=================================== **EDIT**==================================

You have to detect that query parameters have changed. And for that, you may add a listener to queryParameters changings in the constructor of your component. This can be done using your *router* this way :

```js
    constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) { 
        route.queryParams.subscribe(val => { 
            // put the code from ngOnInit here 
        }); 
    }
```

Adding this listener to detect query parameters changes, means you have to move your code from ngOnInit function to this listener. And every time, you navigate, it will be called.

For navigating, you may use html navigation, or ts navigation. If you want it to be in html, you may use :

```html
    <button routerLink="/deposits-withdrawals" [queryParams]="{ type: 'withdrawal' ,'productId': selectedBalance.ProductId }" class="wallet-btns">WITHDRAW {{selectedBalance.ProductSymbol}}</button>
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please let me know what are the other things you want to know. I will provide them too.

Comment: okay , Would you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678403/3428620 ? Tell if it works for you. It should work

Comment: From the above comment, you mean there is no way to do that using query parameters?

Comment: `constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) { route.params.subscribe(val => { // put the code from `ngOnInit` here }); }` 
means that you will add a listener to the route in case query parameters change. 
It means you have to navigate first ( using query parameters , in html or in the ts . 
For example _<button routerLink="/deposits-withdrawals" [queryParams]="{ type: 'withdrawal' ,'productId': selectedBalance.ProductId }" class="wallet-btns">WITHDRAW {{selectedBalance.ProductSymbol}}</button>_ .

**Then** , you detect these changes in the route listener .

Comment: Thank you. It works in ngOnInit itself. I did something like `this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      \\code here
    });` in ngOnInit as you explained above. This works fine. If you update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done  ;) Thank you. Glad it helped

Comment: @AsmaG Thank you. You are the first easy solution I found. I was wondering how such a simple behaviour requires changing the providers and I just needed to subscribe to the route.

Answer (score 11):

The `ngOnInit()` has to be re-invoked when query parameter is updated. This can be achieved as follow:

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing parameters usually won't cause an ngOnInit.

If you are navigating to the same page with different parameter, you can listen to events such as NavigationEnd. based on that you will be able to trigger the functions that you want.

```js
    import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
    export class AppComponent {
    ...
      constructor(public userService: UserService, router:Router) {
        router.events.forEach((event) => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            console.log(location.pathname);
          }
          //NavigationStart
          // NavigationEnd
          // NavigationCancel
          // NavigationError
          // RoutesRecognized
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this.

Suppose you have a container `news-list.component.ts` with `ngOnInit`. It saves current `queryParams` in `currentFilters` and if there is not them makes simple GET request else it makes POST request.

```js
    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        if (!!queryParams) {
          this.currentFilters = <NewsFilter>{...queryParams, offset: 0, size: 6};
          this.news$ = this.newsPostsService.getNewsByFilter(this.currentFilters);
        } else {
          this.news$ = this.newsPostsService.getMainNews();
        }
      });
    }
```

Then you create an component `<news-rubric></news-rubric>` which has following view. You pass there `currentFilters` and take `rubricClick` which you process next.

`news-list.component.html`

```html
    <ml-news-rubrics [currentFilters]="currentFilters"
                     (rubricClicked)="onRubricFilter($event)"
    ></ml-news-rubrics>
```

`news-list.component.ts`

```js
    onRubricFilter(filters: NewsFilter) {
      this.currentFilters = {...filters};
      this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: filters, relativeTo: this.route});
    }
```

And then inside `news-rubric.component.ts` you do something like this:

```js
    onRubricClicked(rubricId: string) {
      // check if filter exists and if not then put ID in filter
      if (!this.currentFilters.filterByAnyRubricIds) { 
        this.putIdInFilter('filterByAnyRubricIds', rubricId, this.currentFilters.filterByAnyRubricIds);
      } else {
        // check if clicked ID is not in filter. put in filter
        if (!this.currentFilters.filterByAnyRubricIds.includes(rubricId)) { 
          this.putIdInFilter('filterByAnyRubricIds', rubricId, this.currentFilters.filterByAnyRubricIds);
        } else { 
          // if ID in filter remove it from filter
          this.removeIdFromFilter('filterByAnyRubricIds', rubricId, this.currentFilters.filterByAnyRubricIds);
        }
      }
      this.rubricClicked.emit(this.currentFilters);
    }
```

There is most tricky code. It makes new filter by updating its *key* with filtered ID.

```js
    private putIdInFilter(key: string, value: any, list: any) {
      if (!list || !(list instanceof Array)) {
        if (!list) {
          this.currentFilters = {...this.currentFilters, [key]: [value]};
        } else {
          this.currentFilters = {...this.currentFilters, [key]: [this.currentFilters[key], value]};
        }
      } else {
        this.currentFilters = {...this.currentFilters, [key]: [...this.currentFilters[key], value]};
      }
    }

    private removeIdFromFilter(key: string, value: any, list: any) {
      if (!list || !(list instanceof Array)) {
        this.currentFilters = <NewsFilter>{
          ...this.currentFilters, [key]: null
        };
        return;
      }
      const filteredValues = [...list.filter(i => i !== value)];
      if (filteredValues.length > 0) {
        this.currentFilters = <NewsFilter>{
          ...this.currentFilters, [key]: filteredValues
        };
      } else {
        delete this.currentFilters[key];
      }
    }
```

And `NewsFilter` it is merely interface like `QueryParams` with keys which are required to be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to resolve a different set of data from the backend using those query parameters and then reinitialize the data inside your component using the new data set from the response.
If that's the case I would suggest to use the following approach:

Make a resolver for your data (implementing the `Resolve` interface) and then subscribe to `route.data` from your activated route which will re-emit with the new data when route and/or query parameters change if you configured the `runGuardsAndResolvers` parameter inside your route config accordingly. 
If you didn't use resolvers before read [here more on them inside the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

An example on what your route config and your `Module` could look like:

```
type Data = any;
const DATA = new InjectionToken<Resolve<Data>>('Data resolver for my component');

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'deposits-withdrawals',
    component: MyComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'pathParamsOrQueryParamsChange',
    data: {
      // Your static data
    },
    resolve: {
      // Resolvers for your dynamic data that should change on path or query params change
      // In your case the source for deposits/withdrawals in your component
      // Name your source as how you like it to be accessible as a property in data
      source: DATA, 
    },
  },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DATA,
      useFactory: (apiService: ApiService): Resolve<Data> => {
        return { 
          resolve: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Data> => {
            // Here you get your latest query params
            const queryParams = route.queryParams; 
            return apiService.sendRequest(queryParams); // Should return Observable<Data>;
          },
        },
      },
      deps: [ApiService],
    }
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Inside `MyComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
class MyComponent {
  
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // Subscribe to route data changes
    this.subscription.add(
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
        // The route data observable will re-emit when your resolver runs and returns new data
        // Do something with the new data.source inside the subscriber/observer
        const source = data.source;
      }),
    );
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks.
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

This is mere a simple example on how you can go about. There are many ways on how to organize this nicely in your code. For example your `ApiService` could of course also implement the `Resolve` interface directly and you could in that case set the service as a resolver immediately (`source: ApiService`).

Don't forget to set the `runGuardsAndResolvers` exlicitly to run on query parameters change. By default it will only run on changing path parameters. Read more on [that topic in the official Angular documentation here](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers).