# Angular 8 Router Link not working in a specific part of the code

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

Inside my code, I used routerLink to redirect the user if he's not authenticated and works perfectly, but in the same page I have couple links that redirect to the suggested post but on click, only the link in the browser changes and the clicked post does not load, here is my current version of the code:

**Note: RouterModule already Import in app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ...
      FaqComponent,

    ],
    imports: [
      RouterModule,
      BrowserModule,
      ...
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: []
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Not working:

```
<h1>Suggested FAQ</h1>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
     <li style="padding: 12px 0px;background-color: transparent;font-weight: bold;" *ngFor="let faq of suggestedFaqs" class="list-group-item">
        <a routerLink="/faq/{{faq.id}}/{{faq.title}}" >{{faq.title}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Works:

```
<div style="margin: 30px 0px;" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
   <a routerLink="/login" class="btn_faq" >login</a>
</div>
```

Path definition in app-routing.module.ts

```
  { path: 'faq/:id/:title', component: FaqComponent},
```

Example:

```
http://localhost:4200/faq/2/Changer%20votre%20langue%20préférée.
```

The route works perfectly when it's clicked outside the FaqComponent but if it's Clicked inside the FaqComponent it doesnt work

Comment: could you show your console errors?

Comment: @StepUp no errors shown, it just doesn't load the new post details, but the link in the browsers changes

Comment: Is the '/faq' route defined with the parameter you're passing in the app.routing.ts file? It should appear as something like { path: 'faq/:title', component: FaqComponent}

Comment: yes its already defined and the same routerLink : [routerLink]="['/faq', faq.id,faq.title]" redirect to the post  in the page that contains all posts

Comment: How does your route look like? `.../faq/1/footitle` Could you show your path?

Comment: I think the problem is that I want to load "Post component" when I am already in the "post component", if that makes any sense

Comment: Please share your app.module  so we can actually see your router definitions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The router only destroys and recreates the component when it navigates
>   to a different route. When only route params or query params are
>   updated but the route is the same, the component won't be destroyed
>   and recreated.

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678356/router-navigate-does-not-call-ngoninit-when-same-page)