# How can I rerender this angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have two components. A header and a search form. The header gives you a form to search for a recipe. When you submit the form, you are redirected to the search page that shows you your search results. This functionality works. However, while I'm on the search page I want to submit another search(from the header). The search page will not re-render and update to show the new search results.

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  query!: any;

  startSearch() {
   this.query = ((document.getElementById('form-control me-2') as 
      HTMLInputElement).value);
   console.log("Query:", this.query);
   this.router.navigate(['/search', this.query])
  }
}
```

header.component.ts

```
<div class="nav-overlay uk-navbar-left uk-flex-1" hidden>
        <div class="uk-navbar-item uk-width-expand">
            <form class="uk-search uk-search-large uk-width-1-1" (ngSubmit)="startSearch();" >
                <input id="form-control me-2" class="uk-search-input" type="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" uk-close="ratio:2" uk-toggle="target: .nav-overlay; animation: uk-animation-fade" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

search.component.ts

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  searchSub!: Subscription;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  
    constructor(
        private searchService: SearchService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    results!: ISearchResults;
    query!: any;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
            this.query = params.get('query');
        });
        this.searchSub = this.searchService
            .search(this.query)
            .subscribe({
                next: results => {
                    this.results = results,
                        console.log("Search query : ", this.query);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.searchSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678356/router-navigate-does-not-call-ngoninit-when-same-page). Basically `ngOnInit()` is not being called because the component is already initialized.
Put the search inside you paramMap subscription, then your results get updated when the route params change.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
        this.query = params.get('query');
        this.searchService
        .search(this.query)
        .subscribe({
            next: results => {
                this.results = results,
                    console.log("Search query : ", this.query);
            }
        });
    
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed.