# How do I rerun "ngOnInit()" after navigating to the same URL (parameter is different)?

Tags: angular

In my app there is a URL like `/organization/campaign/{campaign handle}`.

My goal is to redirect the user to a default `campaign handle` when the user visits the URL with an invalid `{campaign handle}`.

For example, when a user visits `/organization/campaign/doesNotExist`, he should be redirected to `/organization/campaign/defaultCampaign`.

So I added the following code in the `ngOnInit()` method.

```
if (parameterIsInvalid) {
    this.router.navigate(['/organization', 'campaign', defaultCampaign]);
}
```

However, when visting a URL like `/organization/campaign/doesNotExist`, the `ngOnInit()` runs only once, which should be **twice** to work properly:

1. the 1st time `parameterIsInvalid` is true, so `this.router.navigate(['/organization', 'campaign', defaultCampaign]);` runs.
2. the same component is loaded once again. This time `ngOnInit()` runs again, and `parameterIsInvalid` is false, so no redirecting needed and the page displays normally.

But #2 doesn't happen, which leads to the data not fetched (it is fetched in `ngOnInit()`, which is not executed after the redirecting), so the page is empty due to the lack of data.

Looks like although the param in URL is different, the component doesn't reload and `ngOnInit()` doesn't rerun.

I am wondering how to make it happen?

I could use `window.location.reload()`, but it may not be a good practice I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post complete code, not just fragments, there is not enough here to answer the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to navigate to root, or some other URL.

Then navigate back to your default.

The code below is not tested.

```
if (parameterIsInvalid) {
  ((urlSegment: any[]) => {
    this.router.navigate(["/"]).then(() => { // return to root
      this.router.navigate(urlSegment); // then navigate to target url
    });
  })(['/organization', 'campaign', 'defaultCampaign']);
}
```

I think this is not the best answer, but if there is no other alternative, you can use as workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678356/router-navigate-does-not-call-ngoninit-when-same-page is better I think, which is to subscribe to `ActivatedRoute.params` and call methods accordingly.