# How to refresh component UI after route.navigate in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I'm trying to refresh my UI based on a retrieved list from a service. Like this:

**HTML part:**

```
<li *ngFor="let test of testsList" class="list-inline-item">
       <div class="row m-row--no-padding align-items-center">
             <div class="col">
               <button
               [disabled]="test.locked"
               [ngClass]="{locked: test.locked, disabled: test.status == 1}"
               (click)="selectTest(test)"
               class="square"></button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Where my `testsList` comes from a promise on the API and it's retreived in `ngOninit`:

```
this._myService.getAllTests().then((tests: TestDto[]) => {
        this.testsList = tests;
}
```

From a child component, I want to come back to this component (the root one) and paint the updated list of tests. To navigate back to the parent component, I use the `router.navigate(...)`:

```
this._router.navigate(['app/tests/all']);
```

The background data is being updated, as I can check in database and when I refresh manually the page. But when I navigate to it, the UI doesn't show the changes...

I tried several things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827668) and tried also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533351) but I think I didn't implement it in the correct way...

As additional info, I attach the pages structure:

```
/tests (root page)
   |
(child pages)
   |----> all
   |---->description
   |---->....
   |---->summary
```

And I jump from `/all` to `/summary`, I update some data in `/summary` that must be rendered when jumping back to `/all` page.

How can I refresh the UI or bind to the value so it updates whenever the `'app/tests/all'` page is called?

*EDIT:*

```
getAllTests() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._testsService.getAllTests().subscribe( (result) => {
            this.tests = this.orderAsc(result.items);
            resolve(this.tests);
        }, error => {
            console.log('No tests loaded from Database');
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: ChangedetectorRef.detectChanges()

Answer (score 1):

OK, your problem is that you are wrapping a observable with a Promise, and Promises handles only 1 async operation, instead the Observable is like a stream of events. You can see very good explanations of the difference between them here: [What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables)

So, for your case, you could return directly an observable like this:

```
getAllTests() {
  return this._testsService.getAllTests().pipe(
    map((result) => {
      this.tests = this.orderAsc(result);
      return (this.tests);
    }),
    catchError(err => ('No tests loaded from Database'))
  );
}
```

With the map you transform the result that comes from your database and **getAllTests()** is now returning an observable that you can subscribe to in your component like this:

```
this._myService.getAllTests().subscribe((tests: TestDto[]) => {
  this.testsList = tests;
});
```

Or even better, instead of subscribing in the component, you could use the async pipe in the html:

```
<li *ngFor="let test of testsList$ | async" class="list-inline-item">
```

And in your component you have to declare a variable of type **Observable**:

```
  public testsList$: Observable<TestDto[]>;
```

And assign it to the function _testsService.getAllTests() like this:

```
this.testsList$ = this._myService.getAllTests();
```

Comment: Added the function! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the most appropiate way but I added this to the constructor of the Component I need to be refreshed:

```
this._router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
            return false;
          };
```

And it worked...